# Django: What is the most proper value for ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Tags: django, nginx, settings, spoofing

### Question 1

As I know, django has **ALLOWED_HOSTS** option in *settings.py* to prevent from spoofing attacks.

However, I don't know which one is **the most proper value** for ALLOWED_HOSTS **among case 1~3**. (*Or all of them make same result?*)

**Case 1** : `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mydomain.com']`

**Case 2** : `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myipaddress']`

**Case 3** : `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.mydomain.com', 'myipaddress']`

This question is quite related with previous([[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676314/should-server-ip-address-be-in-allowed-hosts-django-setting), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018250/what-is-the-vulnerability-allowed-hosts-is-defending-against)) questions, but I couldn't make a decision clearly.

---

### Question 2

According to [Brent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238506/djangos-suspiciousoperation-invalid-http-host-header/#17477436), editing **nginx's configuration** could yield same result. *(See following codes*)

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn_mydomain.com.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    ...

    ## Deny illegal Host headers
    if ($host !~* ^(mydomain.com|www.mydomain.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

    location  / {
        proxy_pass               http://app_server;
        ...
    }

}
```

Like similar logic first question, what would be the best value to replace `mydomain.com|www.mydomain.com` ?

Answer (score 1):

This kinds of problem seems to be **only occurred under django version 1.5** which is deprecated.

If I set the `server_name`(e.g. mydomain.com) in `nginx configuration` correctly, then nginx would consider direct accessing with IP address as invalid request.

If I didn't include IP address in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, django would report to admin accounts when user access at IP address. On the contrary to this, django would not report when I include IP address in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Following is a sum-up of my thought.

(1) Only include 'domain.com' in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

(2) Set default server and `server_name` correctly from `nginx` side

(3) If you don't want to send error mail in this case, edit `logging` part in *settings.py*